# Overlaying plots

Tags: images, data-visualization, image-processing, plotting

I am looking for a program that can overlay plots.

Example: Given the two following plots, it should produce a single plot containing both curves, using the same x-axis and y-axis.

[image]

[image]

Assume one doesn't have the data underlying the plots (-> one cannot straightforwardly call any plotting library and ask to overlay).

Any OS, any license, any price, any file encoding is fine. Library, CLI or GUI.

Comment: What do you feed into the program? Two PNG images?

Comment: The first graph starts at 0.950 and the second at 0.955: Should the program detect that and automatically distort one of the plots to fit the scale of the other?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Correct, two images, PNG or other format. It should fit the scale, ideally.